# JavaScript getElemendById().innerHTML=data.body.result repeating itself...how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html

I have four buttons that retrieve data from a server.  I'm having an issue where when I click one of the four buttons, I get the correct values, but it fills all four html spans.  So for instance, if I click button1, the results from button1 fill in the spans for all four buttons.  If I click button2, I get the results from button2, but in all four spans as well.

I've tried four different versions of code, and I get slightly different results with all four.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Particle Javascript Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particle-api-js/5/particle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <br>
    <span id="r1"></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay1')">Relay1</button><br>
    <span id="r2"></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay2')">Relay2</button><br>
    <span id="r3"></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay3')">Relay3</button><br>
    <span id="r4"></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay4')">Relay3</button><br>
```

And here are the different versions I've tried

**This code always gives me the data on the first line:**

```
  function variableGet(variableName){
    var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });

    vrGr.then(
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = data.body.result;
      }
      );
  }
```

**This code gives me the info of the button I click on all four lines, but again, its always the same text.**

```
function variableGet(variableName){
    var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });

    vrGr.then(
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = data.body.result;
        document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = data.body.result;
        document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = data.body.result;
        document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = data.body.result;
      }
      );
  }
```

**I tried this as well, but I get the same as I got in the first version, I get the proper data, but only ever on the first line:**

```
 function variableGet(variableName){
    var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });

    vrGr.then(
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = data.body.result
      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = data.body.result
      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = data.body.result
      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = data.body.result
      }
      );
```

**And lastly, I tried this as well, again, I get the proper data, but always on the same line:**

```
  function variableGet(variableName){
      requestURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" + ActualDeviceID + "/" + variableGet + "/?access_token=" + token;
        var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });

    vrGr.then(
      function(requestURL) {
        document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = requestURL.body.result
      },
      function(requestURL) {
        document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = requestURL.body.result
      },
      function(requestURL) {
        document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = requestURL.body.result
      },
      function(requestURL) {
        document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = requestURL.body.result
      }
      );
  }
```

Comment: would be easier to add one more parameter for result: `variableGet('getRelay1', 'r1')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [skobaljic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386703/skobaljic) suggested you can add a second parameter to the onclick like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Particle Javascript Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particle-api-js/5/particle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <br>
  <span id="r1"></span>
  <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay1', 'r1')">Relay1</button><br>
  <span id="r2"></span>
  <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay2', 'r2')">Relay2</button><br>
  <span id="r3"></span>
  <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay3', 'r3')">Relay3</button><br>
  <span id="r4"></span>
  <button type="button" onclick="variableGet('getRelay4', 'r4')">Relay3</button><br>
```

**And then your function could look like:**

```
function variableGet(variableName, r){
    var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });

    vrGr.then(
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById(r).innerHTML = data.body.result;
      }
    );
}
```

Let us know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the correct span id since you already have the number in the variableName.

Pretty quick fix:

```
function variableGet(variableName){
    var vrGr = particle.getVariable({ deviceId: ActualDeviceID, name: variableName, auth: token });
    var spanId = "r" + variableName.slice(-1);
    vrGr.then(
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = data.body.result;
      }
    );
}
```